Karafka on AWS Fargate with MSK: Process Hangs When Consuming Messages One at a Time
I'm running a Karafka application that consumes messages one at a time inside an ECS container on AWS Fargate, using Amazon MSK as my Kafka broker.
Setup Details:
Karafka configuration and code:
class KarafkaApp < Karafka::App
  setup do |config|
    config.kafka = {
      'bootstrap.servers': 'brokers',
      'enable.partition.eof': true,
      'security.protocol': 'sasl_ssl',
      'sasl.mechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
      'sasl.username': 'username',
      'sasl.password': 'password',
    }
    config.client_id = 'users_and_groups_service'
    config.max_messages = 1
    config.consumer_persistence = !Rails.env.development?
    config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
  end

  routes.draw do
    topic 'my_topic' do
      consumer MyConsumer
    end
  end
end

class SingleMessageBaseConsumer < Karafka::BaseConsumer
  attr_reader :message

  def consume
    messages.each do |message|
      @message = message
      consume_one
    
      mark_as_consumed(message)
    end
  end
end

class MyConsumer < SingleMessageBaseConsumer
  def consume_one
    Karafka.logger.info 'starting'
    sleep 3
    Karafka.logger.info 'finished'
  end
end

librdkafka setup in container:
wget https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/archive/refs/tags/v2.3.0.tar.gz && \
tar -xzf v2.3.0.tar.gz && \
cd librdkafka-2.3.0 && \
./configure --enable-sasl --enable-ssl && \
make && \
make install

Problem:
When running the application locally with Kafka from a container, everything works perfectly. However, when deployed to AWS Fargate, the behavior is inconsistent and problematic:

If I send a message that triggers business logic taking around 1-2 seconds to execute, I notice that after about 1 second, the logs suddenly stop as if the process has frozen. This freeze persists until I either send a few more messages or restart the container.

If I simplify the consumer to just include a sleep call and some logging, the logs don't appear at all until I send multiple messages. Even then, logging always stops somewhere in the middle of the message processing.


It might initially seem like the consumer is processing a batch and waiting for more messages to fill it, but the fact that message processing abruptly stops without finishing suggests that this isn't simply a batching issue. The behavior makes me suspect there might be something else going wrong, possibly related to the environment or the configuration.
I actually tried using Ruby Racecar before switching to Karafka, and encountered the same issue.
Questions:

Has anyone encountered similar issues with Karafka on AWS Fargate using Amazon MSK?
Could there be something specific about the way librdkafka is compiled or configured in this environment?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
As I mentioned above, I have also tried using Ruby Racecar, but the behavior was the same.

Can you try setting socket.nagle.disable=true in the config? If you're going to consume one at a time, why not Lambda triggers?

@OneCricketeer Thanks for the advice.
I have tried setting socket.nagle.disable=true, but it didn't affect anything. As for Lambda triggers, we already have a couple of services in Go that are working on the same setup, so I just reused it because we already have it.

Karafka and rdkafka-ruby maintainer here.
While I do not have a clear answer to your issue, here are some things you may want to try:

Set up and enable Web UI. At the freeze moment, you will know exactly what jobs are running.
Web UI provides error tracking, so it should be logged in case of any type of error.
Set up Karafka error instrumentation and print all the logs. Karafka is multi-threaded, and many things happen under the hood. Many errors are not visible directly unless instrumented.
Follow the debugging instructions to generate extensive logs you could share: https://karafka.io/docs/Problems%2C-Troubleshooting-and-Debugging/#debugging
Ensure your auth method is correct and that it can handle long-running processes. Some auth methods like Oauth token setup, when configured incorrectly, may work until the first token refreshes.
Last but not least, feel free to join Karafka Slack: https://karafka.io/slack. Sometimes, it is much easier to cooperate and figure out things during a regular conversation.

If you would be able to post the debug logs (both from Karafka and librdkafka levels) we should be able to figure this one out. I do recall some folks use Karafka with MSK and Fargate already.

Thank you for the advice; it helped me identify the issues.
TL;DR The consumer process was fine; the issues were due to log buffering and a staging misconfiguration.
Logs were buffered before being written to AWS CloudWatch, which made the simple consumer logic appear frozen. In the case of a complex consumer with business logic, staging env misconfiguration caused the business logic that worked locally to fail silently on staging env. The log buffering further complicated diagnosis by cutting off logs just before the bug.

The consumer process was fine.
The issues were due to log buffering. Logs were buffered before being written to AWS CloudWatch, which made the simple consumer appear frozen.
